# Query regarding transpose property in matrix

Tags: matrices

IF $X$ be a 3x3 symmetric matrix and $Y$ be 3x3 matrix skew-symmetric matrix.
If$X^3Y^3$ also represent a matrix $T$.
Then find the value of $T^T$.

My concept let $X^3=A$ and  $Y^3=B$

$T=AB$, using the transpose property
 $T^T=(AB)^T=B^TA^T$

$T^T=(Y^3)^T(X^3)^T$

My query starts from here
I have consulted many books and cannot find the following TYPE property$(Y^3)^T=(Y^T)^3$.

Please recommend me some website where I can get the property.
After this step I can use symmetric and skew-symmetric property.

Comment: Hint: $Y^3=YYY$. Now apply the product property you already know to get its transpose.

Comment: @Rahul I know that $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$ but how do I find the transpose of $(ABC)^T$

Comment: Hint: $ABC=A(BC)$ so $(ABC)^T=(A(BC))^T=(BC)^TA^T=\dots$? Also try it with $ABC=(AB)C$.